# C# I want the url, not the physical pathname

Tags: c#, url, uri

For this line of code;

```
string link = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Contract/Details/" + this.ContractId.ToString());
```

I get the physical pathname on C drive.

What I want is the url, ie

```
http://localhost:1234/Contract/Details/1
```

How do I get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Use the Uri constructor to form a URL relative to the current page
Uri linkUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, "/Contract/Details/" + this.ContractId.ToString());
string link = linkUri.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: this will return current request URL, maybe this is not a "/Contract/Details/1"

Answer (score 3):

There's a great article on .Net paths @ http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx

Take a look at the Url or PathInfo property.

Answer (score 0):

Uri base = new Uri("http://localhost:1234/";);

Uri file = new Uri(host, "/Contract/Details/" + this.ContractId.ToString());

string URL = file.AbsoluteUri;

Comment: Tim Robinson answer is better becouse he is using current request host